# Calculate grayscale percent of a image in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image-processing, colors

I have the next reusable function to determine the total percentage of grayscale in a image. It also works (partially) for GIF images.

The problems this code have are:

- It is slow. But I think maybe this problem cannot be solved since it seem required to parse all the pixels in the image.
- It does not work for many images that are in different pixel formats than those that I'm handling. Like for example: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Nine_steps_stair_in_Lysekil_-_bw.jpg
- It does not take into account multiple dimensions of a GIF image.

I would like to translate my code to the equivalent (or a better) algorithm using the WPF class members to beneffit of its image-processing performance and capabilities, and during that code translation fix the problems I mentioned that could be solved.

How could I do it?. In C# or VB.NET, the choice does not matter.

This is the current code I have:

**VB.NET**

```
Public Shared Function GetGrayScalePercentOfImage(ByVal img As Image) As Double

    Select Case img.PixelFormat

        Case PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale
            Return 100.0R

        Case Else
            Dim pixelCount As Integer = (img.Width * img.Height)
            Dim bytesPerPixel As Integer = (Image.GetPixelFormatSize(img.PixelFormat) \ 8)

            If (bytesPerPixel <> 3) AndAlso (bytesPerPixel <> 4) Then
                Throw New NotImplementedException(message:="Only pixel formats that has 3 or 4 bytes-per-pixel are supported.")

            Else
                Dim GrayscalePercentList As New List(Of Double)

                Dim frameDimension As New FrameDimension(img.FrameDimensionsList(0))
                Dim frameCount As Integer = img.GetFrameCount(frameDimension)

                For frameIndex As Integer = 0 To (frameCount - 1)

                    img.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimension, frameIndex)

                    ' Lock the bitmap's bits.
                    Dim bmp As Bitmap = DirectCast(img, Bitmap)
                    Dim rect As New Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size)
                    Dim data As BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat)

                    ' Get the address of the first line.
                    Dim ptr As IntPtr = data.Scan0

                    ' Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
                    Dim numBytes As Integer = (data.Stride * bmp.Height)
                    Dim rgbValues As Byte() = New Byte(numBytes - 1) {}

                    ' Copy the RGB values into the array.
                    Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes)

                    ' Unlock the bitmap's bits.
                    bmp.UnlockBits(data)

                    ' Iterate the pixels.
                    Dim grayscalePixelCount As Long ' of current frame.
                    For pixelIndex As Integer = 0 To (rgbValues.Length - bytesPerPixel) Step bytesPerPixel

                        Dim c As Color = Color.FromArgb(red:=rgbValues(pixelIndex + 2),
                                                        green:=rgbValues(pixelIndex + 1),
                                                        blue:=rgbValues(pixelIndex))

                        If (c.R = c.G) AndAlso (c.G = c.B) AndAlso (c.B = c.R) Then
                            grayscalePixelCount += 1
                        End If

                    Next pixelIndex

                    Dim frameGrayscalePercent As Double = ((grayscalePixelCount / pixelCount) * 100)
                    GrayscalePercentList.Add(frameGrayscalePercent)

                    grayscalePixelCount = 0
                Next frameIndex

                Return (GrayscalePercentList.Sum() / frameCount)

            End If

    End Select

End Function
```

**C#** (generated with a code converter tool, I didn't tested it.)

```
public static double GetGrayScalePercentOfImage(Image img)
{

    switch (img.PixelFormat)
    {

        case PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale:
            return 100.0D;

        default:
            int pixelCount = (img.Width * img.Height);
            int bytesPerPixel = (Image.GetPixelFormatSize(img.PixelFormat) / 8);

            if ((bytesPerPixel != 3) && (bytesPerPixel != 4)) {
                throw new NotImplementedException(message:"Only pixel formats that has 3 or 4 bytes-per-pixel are supported.");

            } else {
                List<double> GrayscalePercentList = new List<double>();

                FrameDimension frameDimension = new FrameDimension(img.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
                int frameCount = img.GetFrameCount(frameDimension);

                long grayscalePixelCount = 0; // of current frame.

                int tempVar = frameCount - 1;
                for (int frameIndex = 0; frameIndex <= tempVar; frameIndex++) {

                    img.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimension, frameIndex);

                    // Lock the bitmap's bits.
                    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)img;
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
                    BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

                    // Get the address of the first line.
                    IntPtr ptr = data.Scan0;

                    // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
                    int numBytes = (data.Stride * bmp.Height);
                    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[numBytes];

                    // Copy the RGB values into the array.
                    Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes);

                    // Unlock the bitmap's bits.
                    bmp.UnlockBits(data);

                    // Iterate the pixels.
                    for (int pixelIndex = 0; pixelIndex <= rgbValues.Length - bytesPerPixel; pixelIndex += bytesPerPixel) {

                        Color c = Color.FromArgb(red:rgbValues[pixelIndex + 2], green:rgbValues[pixelIndex + 1], blue:rgbValues[pixelIndex]);

                        if ((c.R == c.G) && (c.G == c.B) && (c.B == c.R)) {
                            grayscalePixelCount += 1;
                        }

                    }

                    double frameGrayscalePercent = ((grayscalePixelCount / (double)pixelCount) * 100);
                    GrayscalePercentList.Add(frameGrayscalePercent);

                    grayscalePixelCount = 0;
                }

                return (GrayscalePercentList.Sum() / frameCount);

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not assume that stride equals the bytes per row.  The size of each row is rounded up to a multiple of 4 bytes by padding.  Also, the .Net documentation for the `LockBits` pixelformat argument is misleading.  It is for the pixelformat of the returned `BitmapData` object.  Think of `BitmapData` as a requested view that translates the raw pixelformat to/from the requested pixel format passed to `LockBits`.  See the windows documentation for [Bitmap::LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536298(v=vs.85).aspx).  Also, the conversion of bytes to a Color structure is a waste.

Comment: "You can not assume that stride equals the bytes per row. The size of each row is rounded up to a multiple of 4 bytes by padding" Thanks for comment, but then coulld you show to me how can I properly calculate the bytes per row?.

Comment: What I was trying to convey is that the for-next loop could allow you to be including padding bytes (see: [Image Stride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx) for a graphic that shows this).  You could use two nested loops.  The outer incremented by stride, and the inner starting at the outer loop value, ending at (outer + (width * bytes per pixel) incremented by bytes per pixel).  However, I typically use LockBits to map to a 32 bpp format stored in a jagged array to keep things simple and reduce the need for a large contiguous memory block.

Comment: You need to _read_ the expected amount of bytes for your pixel format, but for each line of pixels you need to _skip over_ the amount in the stride. Note that `Lockbits` actually **converts data to the requested format**, meaning you could avoid the whole problem by taking a 32bit pixel format. Incidentally, for reading alone this should work for any image you put in, regardless of the image's actual format.

Comment: That is a georgeous tip about LockBits, now I can improve all my other algorithms that has the same dumb limitation I made about PixelFormat. Thanks @TnTinMn and Nyerguds